# Inserting filename, reading data, inserting regex, and testing if each line matches

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex, file

This program first displays a menu which shows some options that the user can select. Each option will the respective functions which do some things.

The user can insert a filename, read data from it, enter a regex pattern, test if each line of the file matches the given regex pattern.

Please provide feedback on how I can improve my program.

```
import re

filename = None
readData = None
regex    = None

def test_data():
    '''Checks if each line of data matches the regex'''

    global readData
    global regex

    if regex == None:
        print('Empty regex')
        print('')
        return None

    try:
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
    except:
        print('Invalid regex')
        print('')
        return None
    i = 1
    if readData == None:
        print('Read data is empty')
        print('')
        return None

    for line in readData:
        if pattern.match(line.strip()):
            print(' Line ', i, ':"', line,'"', ' matches current regex', sep='')
        else:
            print(' Line ', i, ':"', line,'"', ' does not match current regex', sep='')
        i += 1
    print('')

def change_regex():
    '''Sets the regex variable'''

    global regex
    print('Current regex is ', end='')
    if regex != None:
        print('"', regex, '"', sep='')
    else:
        print('empty')

    regex = input('Enter new regex: ')
    print('')

def read_file():
    '''Reads data from file if possible'''

    global filename
    global readData
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        readData = file.readlines()
        print('Data read successfully!')
        file.close()
    except TypeError:
        print('filename is empty!')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found!')

    print('')

def change_filename():
    '''Sets the filename variable'''

    global filename
    print('Current filename is ', end='')
    if filename != None:
        print('"', filename, '"', sep='')
    else:
        print('empty')

    filename = input('Enter new filename (with extension): ')
    print('')

def show_menu():
    '''Shows the menu'''

    print('Enter 1 to change filename')
    print('Enter 2 to read file')
    print('Enter 3 to change regex')
    print('Enter 4 to test if read data matches given regex')
    print('Enter 5 to exit')

def main():
    while True:
        show_menu()
        try:
            option = int(input('Option: '))
        except:
            print('Invalid input')
            print('Please enter a valid option')
            print('')
            continue
        if option == 1:
            change_filename()
        elif option == 2:
            read_file()
        elif option == 3:
            change_regex()
        elif option == 4:
            test_data()
        elif option == 5:
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid input')
            print('Please enter a valid option')
            print('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can find some ideas here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/my-early-stage-statistics-homework-assistant/93950#93950

Comment: @outoftime , Thanks. But shouldn't the the post be rolled back to revision 2?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, what are you talking about? What post, what revision?

Comment: @outoftime, [OP changed the code and made answers meaningless](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/93939/revisions). Shouldn't the change be reverted?

Comment: Not really. All I sad in that answer is good to know in any case.

Comment: @outoftime , How do I use a dictionary like in your answer in that post when I want to pass arguments to the respective functions as seen in [my new code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94165/inserting-filename-reading-data-inserting-regex-and-testing-if-each-line-matc?lq=1)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25030/discussion-between-outoftime-and-cool-guy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. Don't use globals, pass variables as function arguments.
2. Follow pep8
3. Don't use `== None`.  `False`, `0`, `0.0`, `None`, and empty sequences like lists or strings are all considered `False`, so in your case you can just do something like `if not regex`.  If you need to test for `None` specifically, use `is None`.
4. Don't do `return None`, just an empty `return` will return `None` automatically.
5. Don't do a blind `except:`, you should always check for a specific exception.
6. For the loop, use `enumerate` to keep track of the current index.
7. Use `with open(filename, 'r'):`.  This will automatically close the file when you leave the `with` block, even if there is an exception, so you don't need to manually close.
8. In `read_file`, don't catch the exception at all.  The default exceptions give the user more information and more useful information than your exceptions, so just let them be handled normally.
9. It is clearer to do something like `print('"%s"' % regex)` rather than `print('"', regex, '"')`.  Or better yet `regex = '"%s"' % regex if regex else 'empty'`, then `print('Current regex is', regex)`.
10. `show_menu` shouldn't be a separate function.

Comment: **Don't use globals, pass variables as function arguments.** this is pure gold, sadly it also is hard to understand for beginners.

Comment: It is no different than anything else.  It is like a `if` block, a `for` block, a `def` block, or any other similar block of code.  You can (but usually shouldn't) put the whole thing in a `try...except` block, or (better) put the `try...except` block inside the `with` block.  *Edit*: The question I am answering seems to have disappeared.  It was about how to use `with` blocks with exception handling.

Comment: Just googled that and found it. Thanks anyway

Comment: That is fine, but next time rather than deleting the comment please put a new comment saying that you have found the answer.